# How I can add php function in style.js file?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, node.js

This code perfect work if it writes in the same PHP file. But if I write a script in my `style.js` file and then call in PHP script `src="style.js"` then select option does not work. It looks like js file does not accept PHP code:

```js
function account_number($sel_acc){
    $output = '';
    foreach($sel_acc as $row){
        $output .= '<option value="'.$row["NominalAccount"].'">'.$row["NominalAccount"].' ' .$row["NominalName"].'</option>';
    }
    return $output;
}

var count = $(".itemRow").length;
$(document).on('click', '#addRow', function(){
    count++;
    var htmlRows = '';
    htmlRows += '<tr>';
    htmlRows += '<td><select type="text" id="idAccounts'+count+'" name="idAccounts[]"><option value="4000">4000</option><?php echo account_number($sel_acc); ?></selected></td>';
    htmlRows += '</tr>';
    $("#inv_sale_detail").append(htmlRows);
});
```

Comment: PHP is not executed in JS files.

Comment: In the PHP, it is writing the javascript that is then executed in the browser with its values. In js, this will not work as you are in the browser running js where it has no idea what PHP is. What you could do is call a PHP file like script src='getJavscript.php' and have that file writing the JS output.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be here:

```
?></selected></td>
```

The closing tag should be `</select>`
At the end of that line.
And the select input does not accept the attribute `type`
Where you have written `type="text"`

Second: When you input `<?php ... ?>` tags in any other file other than a `php` file that has the extension `.php`, it will be parsed as a string and will not produce the result as it would from a `php` file

Comment: is there any solution for Second thing, I need to use this code in various pages and it is difficult to write in all pages separately

Comment: The only workaround is to have the function in a php file:Where you can write something like ```<?php echo '<script>function account_number(){...} //other Javascript stuff here ... account_number(' . $sel_Acc . ') ... //other Javascript stuff here ... </script>'; ?>```